# Send "LED Flash" command using libmodbus

Tags: c, modbus, plc, modbus-tcp

Is it possibe and if so to send
[LED Flash command](https://youtu.be/q85KdyYwrNM) to IFM AY1020 device using libmodbus?

I can archive it via browser:
[image: Screenshoct]

But i need to do it from C code.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should probably read the device documentation.

Comment: communicating with a MODBUS is relatively simple.  However, you probably will need a converter from RS232 to MODBUS.  You will need to learn the format of the MODBUS messages.  You will need to learn which 'coils' control the leds and what those coils expect in the form of data.